# Can I upload private content to my app that lives in S3 bucket but I access it through cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have an app that lives in S3 bucket, I created Cloudfront distribution and attached to my S3 bucket. Now I can access my app through Cloudfront, so that my s3 bucket is private. I have private data that I need to upload it to my app to do some analysis.. In this case, is this solution (app served on CLoudfront and hosted in S3 bucket) a good one to host private data?

Comment: You've tagged this with `aws-lambda` but haven't mentioned it in your question text. Where do you need to access this private data, in a Lambda function?

Comment: yes you may put your private data on S3 and keep it secure. The way we keep it secure is by providing proper inline access policies to s3 bucket. In your case you want to block public access and provide access to only cloudfront

Comment: @sachsom So I already have the private data on S3 bucket (which is secure), if I login to my website (which also lives in a private S3 bucket) through cloudfront, I should not have any problem with worrying about uploading the private data to the website that people can access through cloudfront, right? My point is that I would like the website that hosts on aws to be secure (in terms of uploading private data), so that no third party can have access to..